# Python Confusion Matrix for Logistic Regression

Tags: python, logistic-regression, confusion-matrix

After running this code:

```
from sklearn.metrics import confusion_matrix 
conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(X_train_p, y_train_p) 
  
print ("Confusion Matrix : \n", conf_matrix)
```

I got this following error:
`len() of unsized object`

Comment: It will be easier for someone to help you if you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Also, when you report a Python error, it is helpful to include the *complete* traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  There is useful information in there, including the line that generated the error.

Answer (score 0):

That error is usually caused by a call of `squeeze()` by an array with a single element. Make sure that your prediction and target arrays have more than one element.

As an aside, you might want to double-check `confusion_matrix`'s signature or rename `X_train_p` - the first parameter of `confusion_matrix` should be the targets, while a capital X usually indicates a feature matrix.